# Convert Minute into HH:MM:SS format in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

**Input:-**

```
Minute = 1220;
```

**Output:-**

```
Time = 20:20:00;
```

How can I get the minute value into a time in Angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `Pipe` in angular

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'minuteSeconds'
})
export class MinuteSecondsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number): string {
    let  temp = value * 60;
    const hours = Math.floor((temp/3600));
    const minutes: number = Math.floor((temp/ 60)/60);
    const seconds=Math.floor(temp % 3600 % 60);
    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
}
```

In template file you can use the pipe as below

```
<p>{{1200|minuteSeconds}}</p>
```